# SQL Left Joins and then an other Join on that results

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out this query.

I need to join about 4 tables on a query.
I have another Left join to see if the items are associated in another table and then I need to do a JOIN on that results to see which campaign it is associated with.

The issue is that some transactions have campaigns and others do not.

```
select  a.Applications,
                a.Clicks,
                isnull(a.Datacaptures,0) as Datacaptures,
                a.Aggration_day,
                a.MediaUsed_id,
                a.mediatrackingid_fk,
                a.tracking_type,
                t.Tracking_info,
                m.MediaName,
                DATEPART(dayofyear, Aggration_day) AS DayofYear,
                c.Title as Campaigntitle,
                c.campaign_id,
                i.title,
                i.start_date,
                i.end_date,
                i.IO_number 
from    Aggeration_day a
        JOIN    tracking_types t on a.tracking_type = t.Tracking_type_id
        JOIN    MediaUsed m on m.media_used_id = a.MediaUsed_id
        JOIN    MediaTrackingItems i on a.mediatrackingid_fk = i.mediatrackingid
        LEFT join   Campaign_items CI ON  a.mediatrackingid_fk = CI.mediatrackingid_FK
        JOIN    Campaigns c ON  CI.campaign_id_fk = c.campaign_id
```

The goal is to get the campaign name back if it is associated with a campaign or or just a null.

I can not figure this one out.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. Plus provide which rdbms you are using.

Comment: I can get the query to work if there are Campaigns  but the issue is with the last two Left join and then trying to Join on that resutl

 LEFT join   Campaign_items CI ON  a.mediatrackingid_fk = CI.mediatrackingid_FK
        JOIN    Campaigns c ON  CI.campaign_id_fk = c.campaign_id

This is what fails

Comment: ^the last join is leading to an inner join overall.

Comment: Once a table is left joined, other tables dependent on that table also need to be left joined; so `LEFT JOIN Campaigns c ON  CI.campaign_id_fk = c.campaign_id`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery like this -

```
SELECT 
a.Applications, 
a.Clicks, 
isnull(a.Datacaptures,0) as Datacaptures, 
a.Aggration_day, 
a.MediaUsed_id, 
a.mediatrackingid_fk, 
a.tracking_type, 
t.Tracking_info, 
m.MediaName, 
DATEPART(dayofyear, Aggration_day) AS DayofYear, 
c.Title as Campaigntitle, 
c.campaign_id, 
i.title, 
i.start_date, 
i.end_date, 
i.IO_number 
FROM Aggeration_day a 
JOIN tracking_types t 
ON a.tracking_type = t.Tracking_type_id 
JOIN MediaUsed m 
ON m.media_used_id = a.MediaUsed_id 
JOIN MediaTrackingItems i 
ON a.mediatrackingid_fk = i.mediatrackingid 
LEFT join (
           Select ci.mediatrackingid, 
                  c.Campaign_Id, 
                  c.campaigntitle 
           FROM Campaign_items CI 
           JOIN Campaigns c 
           ON CI.campaign_id_fk = c.campaign_id
           ) ci 
ON a.mediatrackingid_fk = CI.mediatrackingid_FK
```

Comment: I tried this but there is way to much data for the sub query.

Comment: @MatthewFriedman  So you want to get all the Applications/clicks but only the matching campaigns? If so the left join should have been only on the Campaign table, not Campaign items table. What's the rationale behind that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to "follow on" using left joins to any tables that are dependent on the original left join (see query 1 below).

You can also "nest" joins, although this is not commonly used and can be difficult to follow in complex queries (see query 2 below). In this method the inner join to campaigns forms a derived table prior to the left join conditions being applied which have been placed after the inner join (*yes, confusing!*).

Or you can form your own "derived table" by using a subquery, and join that subquery (see query 3 below). This is easier to follow than using nested joins seen in query 2.

See these queries operating at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdbc4f/3)

**Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Campaigns     (`id` int, `Title` varchar(14));
INSERT INTO Campaigns     (`id`, `Title`)
VALUES    (1, 'First Campaign')
;

CREATE TABLE Campaign_items    (`id` int, `campaign_id` int, `media_fk` int);
INSERT INTO Campaign_items     (`id`, `campaign_id`, `media_fk`)
VALUES
  (201, 1, 3001),
  (202, 1, 4001)
;

CREATE TABLE Media     (`media_id` int);
INSERT INTO Media     (`media_id`)
VALUES
    (3001),
    (4001),
    (5001)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      a.media_id, ci.campaign_id, c.Title
from media a
left join Campaign_items ci on a.media_id = ci.media_fk
left join Campaigns c on ci.campaign_id = c.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdbc4f/3/0)**:

```
| media_id | campaign_id |          Title |
|----------|-------------|----------------|
|     3001 |           1 | First Campaign |
|     4001 |           1 | First Campaign |
|     5001 |      (null) |         (null) |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select
      a.media_id, ci.campaign_id, c.Title
from media a
left join Campaign_items ci 
      inner join Campaigns c on ci.campaign_id = c.id
      on a.media_id = ci.media_fk
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdbc4f/3/1)**:

```
| media_id | campaign_id |          Title |
|----------|-------------|----------------|
|     3001 |           1 | First Campaign |
|     4001 |           1 | First Campaign |
|     5001 |      (null) |         (null) |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select
      a.media_id, ci.campaign_id, ci.Title
from media a
left join (
    select ci.*, c.title
    from Campaign_items ci
    inner join Campaigns c on ci.campaign_id = c.id
    ) ci on a.media_id = ci.media_fk
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdbc4f/3/2)**

```
| media_id | campaign_id |          Title |
|----------|-------------|----------------|
|     3001 |           1 | First Campaign |
|     4001 |           1 | First Campaign |
|     5001 |      (null) |         (null) |
```